# Pagination of SQL output

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem, im trying to make some pagination for my code here but im having trouble, whatever i do it's seem i cant get it to work and would like some assistance if possible, i tried something similar to this example 1 but never got it working :/

Example1:

```
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
$perpage = 5;
if ($page<1) $page = 0;
```

MyCode

```
<?php

echo '<div id="block" border="1" width="200" style="float:center">';
$i = 0;
$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER by ID LIMIT 30");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)){

    $id=$rows['id'];
    echo '<a href="mypage.com/index.php?img='. $id .'">
        <img src="/thumb/'. $id .'.jpg" width="125" height="125" alt="" />
    </a>';

    $i++;
    if($i == 10) {
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';
        $i = 0;
    }
}
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER by ID LIMIT 30");
```

To :

```
$start = $page * $perpage;
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER by ID LIMIT $start, $perpage ");
```

Comment: Still did not work, the limit LIMIT 30 is just there when i wanted to se how it looks, when i tested it with pagenation i removed it :/

Comment: Are you sure, the $page and $perpage variables are handled correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use limit 30... It will always return the first 30 lines... You should use something like: LIMIT $page*$perpage,$perpage

This will tell mysql to start at X, so $page*$perpage, and select Y lines, $perpage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `OFFSET` clause to your SQL. To calculate it, you simply do

```
$offset=$pageNumber * $resultsPerPage
```

`$pageNumber` is 0 based and `$resultsPerPage` is the same as value in `LIMIT` clause